# In OOP reading from text file should be a Independent class method?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a class that only have main which read in some txt and do the algorithms.

my class is look like:

```
class doThejob{
     public static void main(String args[]){
            //*****start part A******
           //do the reading from text file, and tokenize it
           // process into the form I need,
           //about 10-30 lines of codes
           //******End of part A*****

           //then run the algorithms
           algorithm alg=new aglorithm();
           Object output = alg.x(input);

           //****Part B**** output to txt, about 10~40 lines

     }
}

class algorithm{
      private void  a(Object x){
             //do something
           return (Object)result;
      }

}
```

Can anyone tell me should I extract those part A and part B to a new class ,and then setup them as a public method .like below

```
class Io{
    public Object readFromTxt(String path){
    }
    public void outputToTxt(String path){
    }

}
```

And if I setup them , and then use it like below, is that more OOP?

```
class doThejob{
     public static void main(String args[]){
           Io dataProcess= new Io();

           Object input = dataProcess.readFromTxt(args[0]);
           algorithm alg=new aglorithm();
           Object output =alg.x(input);

           dataProcess.readFromTxt(args[1],output);

     }
}

class algorithm{
      private Object  a(Object x){
             //do something
      }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it the way you fill is more readable.

Separating this in another class is according to the Single Responsability Principle. It will help making the code more readable and easy to change later on.

If you want to expand more on this, you could create an interface (eg.: IIO) for input and output. This way you can implement this interface in the IO class, renaming it to FileIO. Anytime you want to create another form of IO, like database access, you just have to create a DatabaseIO class that implements this interface and change the instance in the main method for this new type:

```
public interface IIO
{
    string Read();
    void Write(string text);
}

public class FileIO : IIO
{
     string path;

     public FileIO(string filePath)
     {
         path = filePath;
     }


     public string Read()
     {
         // read from file and return contents
     }

     public void Write(string text)
     {
         // write to file
     }
}

public class SqlServerIO : IIO
{
    SqlConnection conn;

    public SqlServerIO(string connectionStringName)
    {
        // create the connection
    }

    public string Read()
    {
        // read from database
    }

    public void Write(string text)
    {
        // write to database
    }
}
```

Extracting interfaces makes the code more maintenable by alowing to switch implementations anytime without messing with working code. It also facilitates unit testing.